# I need help with the header

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

[image]

Hello everyone, how can I make that header?

Thanks You

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}

\fancyhead[L]{Bla Bla Bla}
\fancyhead[R]{Bla Bla Bla}
\fancyhead[C]{\headrule\vspace{-15pt}} %1
\fancyhead[C]{\rule{\headwidth}{1pt}\vspace{-11pt}} %2
```

Use the line %1 if you want both lines with the same thickness. In your picture it looks like the lower line is thicker; this can be done with line %2.

%1 [image: Result 1]

%2[image: Result 2]

Comment: Thanks you very much!!!

Comment: @H4r0ld, instead of posting a “Thank you” as a comment, you should thank Pieter van Oostrum by upvoting his answer (with the upward pointing arrow to the left of it; you need 15 reputation points before you can upvote) and [accepting it](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).